# Sorting arrays by date with datetime in python 3.10

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, datetime

**I have tried all sorts of code but none of it works so far, this is as close as I have gotten all of them get a similar error**

Heres the data i want to sort

```
{'15/2/2022': 'C:\\Users\\me\\filelocation\\Stuff\\codestuff\\Python\\PDF\\files\\paySlip15Febuary.pdf', 
'18/1/2022':' C:\\Users\\me\\filelocation\\Stuff\\codestuff\\Python\\PDF\\files\\paySlip18January.pdf' }
and so on
```

This is the code i am using currently, but i have tried much more

```
def key(s):
    fmt = "%d-%m-%Y"
    s = ''.join(s.rsplit(':', 1))  # remove colon from offset
    return datetime.strptime(s, fmt)     

sorted(dates.values(), key=key)
```

No matter how many different things i try i get this error.
Btw if you are wondering i am creating an array of dates from a list

`raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help if you could post the code and the example data as a minimum reproducible example. In particular, "reproducible" means we'd like to be able to copy-paste your code and get the same error that you do. But right now we can't, because your code doesn't include the definition of variable `dates`, so if we try to run your code, we'll get an error "`NameError: name 'dates' is not defined.`".

Comment: In particular I'm a bit confused as to what is the "colon" that you're trying to "remove from offset". I can't see colons in the strings that you showed.

Comment: Also try replacing `"%d-%m-%Y"` with `"%d/%m/%Y"`. Perhaps that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: your input seems to be a dictionary, so `s = ''.join(s.rsplit(':', 1))` doesn't make sense to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys here is the correct answer

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(dates.items(), key = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d/%m/%Y'), reverse=True))
```

Comment: no need to say sorry - to make this answer more useful, I'd suggest to add the missing import `from datetime import datetime`. Also, you don't need OrderdDict; you can obtain it like `d_sorted = dict(sorted(dates.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d/%m/%Y"), reverse=True))`